# I want to play each button for each video in pure JS

Tags: javascript, event-handling, components, dom-events, code-reuse

I have a page where I have multiple videos I created one custom button to play video
The problem is I want to write a single JS to achieve this without writing multiple js code for each video

```
<video id="video"> </video>
<button id="circle-play-b">play</button

<video id="video"> </video>
<button id="circle-play-b">play</button
```

JS

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");
                                                        
  var circlePlayButton = document.getElementById("circle-play-b");
console.log(video);
function togglePlay() {
    if (video.paused || video.ended) {
        video.play();
    } else {
        video.pause();
    }
}

circlePlayButton.addEventListener("click", togglePlay);
video.addEventListener("playing", function () {
    circlePlayButton.style.opacity = 0;
});
video.addEventListener("pause", function () {
    circlePlayButton.style.opacity = 1;
});
```

I have an option to add unique id to each video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid approach was to treat the video and button structure as a reusable component.

- Thus one would provide a generically written (no equally named `id` attributes) closed html structure ( `<video/>` and `<button/>` elements are embedded within a parent or root element).
- Then one would implement an initializing function which queries such HTML structures/components and registers every event handler needed.
- Of cause any handler and helper function is implemented (and named) in a way that it targets exactly one problem/task a time ( ... which enables code-reuse as shown with the next provided example code) ...

```js
function getToggleControl(elmVideo) {
  return elmVideo
    .closest('figure')
    .querySelector('button');
}
function updateToggleControl(toggleControl, isPaused) {
  const { dataset } = toggleControl;  
  const controlText = isPaused
    ? dataset.textTogglePlay
    : dataset.textTogglePause;

  toggleControl.textContent = controlText;
  toggleControl.title = controlText;
}

function handleToggleState({ currentTarget: toggleControl }) {
  const elmVideo = toggleControl
    .closest('figure')
    .querySelector('video');

  if (elmVideo) {
    const isPaused = elmVideo.paused || elmVideo.ended;

    if (isPaused) {
      elmVideo.play();
    } else {
      elmVideo.pause();
    }
    updateToggleControl(toggleControl, !isPaused);  
  }
}

function handleVideoPlaying({ currentTarget: elmVideo }) {
  const toggleControl = getToggleControl(elmVideo);

  if (toggleControl) {
    toggleControl.style.opacity = .2;

    updateToggleControl(toggleControl, false);
  }
}
function handleVideoPaused({ currentTarget: elmVideo }) {
  const toggleControl = getToggleControl(elmVideo);

  if (toggleControl) {
    // initially enable the video pause/play button.
    toggleControl.disabled && (toggleControl.disabled = false);

    toggleControl.style.opacity = 1;

    updateToggleControl(toggleControl, true);
  }
}

function initVideoPausePlay() {
  document
    .querySelectorAll('figure[data-video-pause-play] video')
    .forEach(elmVideo => {

      elmVideo.addEventListener('canplay', handleVideoPaused);

      elmVideo.addEventListener('pause', handleVideoPaused);
      elmVideo.addEventListener('playing', handleVideoPlaying);

      getToggleControl(elmVideo)
        ?.addEventListener('click', handleToggleState);
    });
}
initVideoPausePlay();
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
figure { display: inline-block; width: 40%; }
figure video { display: inline-block; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<figure data-video-pause-play>
  <video controls muted>
    <source src="https://ia902803.us.archive.org/15/items/nwmbc-Lorem_ipsum_video_-_Dummy_video_for_your_website/Lorem_ipsum_video_-_Dummy_video_for_your_website.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
    <source src="https://archive.org/embed/nwmbc-Lorem_ipsum_video_-_Dummy_video_for_your_website/Lorem_ipsum_video_-_Dummy_video_for_your_website.HD.mov" type="video/quicktime"> 
  </video>

  <button
    disabled
    class="circle-play-b"
    data-text-toggle-play="play"
    data-text-toggle-pause="pause">
    ...
  </button>
</figure>

<figure data-video-pause-play>
  <video controls muted>
    <source src="https://ia902803.us.archive.org/15/items/nwmbc-Lorem_ipsum_video_-_Dummy_video_for_your_website/Lorem_ipsum_video_-_Dummy_video_for_your_website.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
    <source src="https://archive.org/embed/nwmbc-Lorem_ipsum_video_-_Dummy_video_for_your_website/Lorem_ipsum_video_-_Dummy_video_for_your_website.HD.mov" type="video/quicktime"> 
  </video>

  <button
    disabled
    class="circle-play-b"
    data-text-toggle-play="play"
    data-text-toggle-pause="pause">
    ...
  </button>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set seperate listeners for each video elements.And use class names instead of id.

document.getElementByClassName returns array of elements. Iterates over array and set listeners for each elements.

Html

```
<video class="videos"> </video>
<button class="circle-play-b">play</button>

<video class="videos"> </video>
<button class="circle-play-b">play</button>
```

Js

```
var videos = document.getElementsByClassName("videos");
                                                        
var circlePlayButton = document.getElementsByClassName("circle-play-b");

for (let i = 0; i < circlePlayButton.length; i++) {
  let playBtn = circlePlayButton[i];
  let video = videos[i];
  function togglePlay() {
    if (video.paused || video.ended) {
        video.play();
    } else {
        video.pause();
    }
  }
  playBtn.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
  video.addEventListener("playing", function () {
    playBtn.style.opacity = 0;
  });
  video.addEventListener("pause", function () {
      playBtn.style.opacity = 1;
  });
}
```

Hope it helps to solve your issue

Comment: Can't we use for each or something

Comment: Yeah. Use for... Loop to implement above logic

Comment: can u write the code and guide me

Comment: @taruuunnn Code added in above comment.. Hope it helps.